# Encode AngularJS expression

Tags: html, angularjs

**Introduction :**

I have a expression

**`{{ track.title }}`**

it contains one word or more than one word.
**`i.e`** **`xyz`** or **`xyz abc`**

This `track.title` is then used in a URL.

```
http://www.example.com/{{ track.title }}
```

**Problem :**

this url is working fine with one word in `track.title` but it will break with more than one words.

So, I want to know is there any way to encode the url so that it will not break while sharing.

Any immediate help will be highly appreciable. Thanks

Comment: personally I prefer to create a slug that removes whitespace and non url compliant characters and replace with `-` or `_`. Makes it more human readable

Comment: @charlietfl I would do the same, using a slug is the nicest way to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to escape the spaces in your title somehow.

For readability, instead of using something like `xyz%20abc`, you might replace them with hyphens or underscores instead. `xyz-abc` or `xyz_abc`

Since you still want the title displayed on the page to be unescaped, you may want to create a new variable to hold the escaped version.

`track.url = track.title.replace(' ', '-');`

Comment: that's not enough sanitizing for a url and will only replace first instance

Comment: I was thinking that you could apply the `replace` when you pull in the data - for each track object, add the `url` property generated by sanitizing the title.  I could probably have clarified that better in my answer. As for hyphens not being enough sanitizing, why is this? What would be a better sanitization scheme?

Comment: just meant there are other non compliant url characters also and `replace` isn't global without a modifier